# How does mySQL round float numbers when inserted for int column

Tags: mysql, sql, floating-point, integer

I have a columns in mySQL 8.0 with type `int(11)`.

How would it round float numbers? for example, what will happen if I insert 23.4 and 23.9, will both of them be round up to 23? or 23.4 will be converted to 23 and 23.9 to 24?

Also, can I change the column type to float without deleting the existing data?

Sorry for the basic questions, I'm new at this.

Comment: Surely it would be quicker to test this than ask?

Comment: @Strawberry - you are right, but I don't have proper permissions to do that, it is not my private database...

Comment: You have permission to use sql. That's all you need -as Akina succinctly demonstrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[<kbd>DEMO fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce4cde3b25659bad994dc30831fdddfd)

It shows that the values are rounded "out of zero" - i.e. positive with fractional part 0.5 or more are rounded up whereas negative are rounded down.

Comment: thanks, did you try it of found some docs with this answer? also, can I change the columns type without deleting existing values?

Comment: *did you try it of found some docs with this answer?* No. If I need in definite rounding I never use implicit rounding. There are CEILING(), FLOOR() and ROUND() functions which' output is described strictly.